# How to add new slot to already existing class?

Tags: r, unmarked-package

I have variable `mod` of class `unmarkedFitPCount` from package `unmarked` and I need to add a new attribute to that class:

```
mod@new_attr <- 1
```

I get an error:

> ‘new_attr’ is not a slot in class “unmarkedFitPCount”

I need to add this new attribute *without creating a new derived class*, because I need all those functions to work on this object. This is supposed to be just a very lightweight temporary hack. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you just make a list with your `unmarkedFitPCount` as one elements and `new_attr` as a second? Not elegant but avoids making a whole new class.

Answer (score 7):

What about: `attributes(mod)$new_attr <- 1`.

The core function `attributes` accesses an object's attributes. In this example you create a new attribute `new_attr` and assign it the value of 1.

You can then access the newly created attribute via `attributes(mod)$new_attr`.